# Can I use 2.5kW solar panels to power 2kW rated grid tie solar inverter?

Tags: inverter, solar-energy

Can I use 2.5kW solar panels (10x 250 watts) to power a 2kW rated grid tie solar inverter? Will anything blow up?

Panels: 10x 250W, 36V panels

Inverter: 2kW with max input voltage: 500V

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: usage, not an engineering question.

Comment: then, where should I post it?

Comment: Sounds like that might work on the best sunny days only...

Comment: why? it already gives about 230V 1.9kV.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a solar inverter be damaged if installed capacity is much larger than demand?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/445862/can-a-solar-inverter-be-damaged-if-installed-capacity-is-much-larger-than-demand)

Comment: Sustainable living SE, they could sure use the questions...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Most of the time, the panels won't be generating 2.5kW anyway.  But on a really sunny day, the inverter will only draw as much power from the panels as it can process.